# How do I change the format of logs in the AWS C++ SDK

Tags: aws-sdk-cpp

I'm currently using the `Aws::Utils::Logging::ConsoleLogSystem` to log to stdout. This is great as my application logs to stdout too.

However, the AWS C++ SDK is a different format than my current format. i.e where it seems the SDK does

`[LEVEL] TIMESTAMP Class [threadid] message`

I want to change the order of these(and ideally change timestamp format) to match the rest of my application.

Anyway to change the formatter or format of these logs?

I found this, which is really the thing I want to change
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/blob/main/src/aws-cpp-sdk-core/source/utils/logging/FormattedLogSystem.cpp#L20

That doesn't look like something I can really mess with. But maybe I am looking at this the wrong way

Answer (score 0):

With the way the code is written, I don't think there is a way to do this.

i.e. JUST changing the format of the output.

So I went and just made my own logger. Basically copied
Aws::Utils::Logging::ConsoleLogSystem
Aws::Utils::Logging::FormattedLogSystem

And customized them for what I wanted to do.